# how to no counting the cover and the abstract pages?

Tags: counters

I was vieweing posts but, I can´t find the solution.

I have a cover, an post-cover page, and an abstract page.

How can I do to starting counting on the next page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place `\pagenumbering{gobble}` in the preamble before your cover, post-cover and abstract page if you want them to have no numbering.

Then, where the point where you want the page numbering to start, reset the counter with `\pagenumbering{arabic}` (or roman or whatever.)  Next, reset the counter with `\setcounter{page}{#}` where # is the page number that you want to start numbering from.

Answer (score 1):

Write

```
\setcounter{page}{0}
```

on that page